# How can I redirect all domains to https in Varnish?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, https, varnish

I'm using

```
Apache on port 8080
Nginx on 443
Varnish on 80
```

I don't want to change my varnish configuration every time when I add new domain to server.
I want to know if there is any regex or variable so that varnish redirect all domains to https.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host ~ "example.com") {
       set req.http.x-redir = "https://example.com" + req.url;
       return(synth(850, ""));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 850) {
       set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
       set resp.status = 301;
       return (deliver);
    }
}
```

I have

example.com
abc.com
xyz.com
123.com
www.420.com
abc.123.com

I want all of them to redirect to https with their subdomains ( and all future domains if possible).

Thank you.

Comment: the frontend and only server who deals SSL should do that generally.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.host == "www.example.com" &&
    req.url ~ "^/admin")
{

  if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {
    return (synth(850, "Moved Permanently"));
  }

return (pass);
}
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}


sub vcl_synth {
  if(resp.status == 850) {
    set resp.http.Location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    set resp.status = 301;
}
```